# Passing value to controller function codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I want to get single name of item from database

i created this module

```
public function get_itm_name($id)
{
   $this->db->select('name');
   $this->db->from('items');
   $this->db->where('item_id', $id);
   return $this->db->get();
}
```

I wrote the the controller code like this

```
    public function get_item_name($id)
    {
       $this->load->model('item');        
       $item = $this->Item->get_itm_name($id);     
       $this->db->order_by('name', 'asc');
       $name = array();               
        foreach($item->result() as $result)
        {            
            $name[$result->category][] = $result->name;     
        }   
        echo json_encode($name);
    }
```

Now the real issue inside the view there is already code which i want to modify to add item name 
Here is the view code which contains jquery

```
$.getJSON( '<?php echo site_url($controller_name."/get_item_categories"); ?>', function(data)
 {
        var items = [];     
        $.each( data, function (key,val)
        {                
                items.push("<div id='quickpick' class='btn-group' style='padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 2px;'>");
                items.push("<button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary'>" ); 
                items.push(key + "<span class='dropdown-toggle'></span>");
                items.push("<button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>");
                items.push("<span class='caret'></span>");
                items.push("<span class='sr-only'></span>");
                items.push("</button>");
                items.push("<ul class='dropdown-menu scrollable-menu'>");
                $.each(val,function(ikey,ival) 
                {
                    items.push("<li><a onclick='additem(" + ival + ")'> "+ival+"</a></li>"); 
                });
                items.push( "</ul>");
                items.push( "</div>");       
                console.log(items);             
        });

    $("#quickpick").html(items.join(""));
    $('#quickpickhide').dblclick(function() { $('#quickpick').toggle()} );

     // Get Items   

});
```

I want to call the name here as i have id of the item in the javascript variable "ival"

```
items.push("<li><a onclick='additem(" + ival + ")'> "+ WANT THE NAME HERE +"</a></li>");
```

I want the name to show inside the anchor tag i am already getting the id but i am not able to get the name as i don't know how to call the controller which will include an argument id.

Kindly help me as i am new to Codeigniter if my question is not proper kindly suggest corrections thanks.

Comment: no idea what your query returns? try to see it in your browser's console using `console.dir(data)`, put that right after your $.getJSON call and check the object returned. Adapt your code corresponding to this output...

Comment: Data contains Bar BQ: Array(1)0: "2" this first is the category name which i am printing inside              
items.push(key + "<span class='dropdown-toggle'></span>");                          
Bar BQ next is items which are assigned to the category i am getting the item id which are printed this way $.each(val,function(ikey,ival) 
                {
                    items.push("<li><a onclick='additem(" + ival + ")'> "+ival+"</a></li>"); 
                });

Comment: now i want to get item name by passing the parameter id to the controller inside $.each(val,function(ikey,ival){  } ival contains the item id if i pass this to the function somehow i will get the name back